# CTLineGetTypographicBounds(_CTLine, &_ascent, &_descent, &_leading); iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10

```
_lineWidth = CTLineGetTypographicBounds (_CTLine, &_ascent, &_descent, &_leading);
```

In iOS 9  a line of text are the expression of the numerical _ascent _descent will be larger than a row is the text of the situation

In iOS 10 under Emoji especially when the number of _descent _ascent two values are smaller than the iOS 9.

The calculated height of `height = _ascent + _descent` was smaller than that on iOS 9